# Removing background-color from all the text in the page, regardless whether we have a selection or not

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection, highlight

We have the following Javascript code:

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    document.designMode = "on";

        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }

    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

// This is the highlighting function. It takes a color as an argument.
function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {

        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}


// This returns the highlight to transparent (no highlighting) when the user clicks away in the document.
function body() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function(event){
      highlight('transparent');
    }
  );
}
```

It works like this:

When there's text selected in a page, if you press a button (say an extension popup) then that text gets a yellow highlight and is automatically deselected.

That's where the problem comes in.

Because the text is automatically deselected, I cannot revert the highlight back to the same text (since there's no selection anymore)

So the focus of this question is on the last part, namely:

```
function body() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function(event){
      highlight('transparent');
    }
  );
}
```

This only works if I select the same text and click anywhere in the document.

How I would like it to work is to be able to click anywhere in the document, and any highlighted text to be set back to original (or transparent if original not possible).

I'm aiming for any text because I have no selection here.

So basically this function should work like this:

if selection present and button pressed > highlight the selection and automatically remove all selections.

when a click is registered anywhere in the page, remove any highlighting on any text, regardless of whether there's a selection or not.

Again, this code seems to work very good up until the last part, the 'removing any highlight present' part.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your call to highlight from body to have an extra parameter prevRange which is a global one. and then reset prevRange to be undefined after the call.

The signature of highlight can be

> function highlight(colour, oldRange) {

and start like

```
function highlight(colour, oldRange) {
    var range, sel, oldSelection;
    if (typeof(oldRange) !== 'undefined') {
        oldSelection = window.getSelection();     
        oldSelection.removeAllRanges();   
        oldSelection.addRange(oldRange);
    }
    sel = oldSelection || window.getSelection(); 
    if (sel) {
```

The rest of the function can work with sel.
The old range will need to be stored in prevRange just before the deselection, and makeEditableAndHighlight can also get the optional parameter oldRange (and have a test similar to the one after the "function highlight(colour, oldRange) {" signature)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast response. I tried variations of this, I understand the code but I don't know how exactly to integrate it. How would I use this in a separate function?

Comment: Well I have this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/SPSxt/ but I don't understand how to make prevRange global if oldRange is not, I'm also not sure what parameters I should pass to the body function now.

Comment: I'm sorry my suggestion still isn't clear enough :/

In body: highlight('transparent'); -> highlight('transparent', prevRange);

You should also define prevRange at the top of everything for your own sanity... and store oldRange in prevRange before the deselection.